# Hidden relationships with javascript machine learning

Tags: javascript, machine-learning

I have a long array of objects that are created to track daily actions.

Example:

```
[
    {name:'workout', duration:'120', enjoy: true, time:1455063275, tags:['gym', 'weights']},
    {name:'lunch', duration:'45', enjoy: false, time:1455063275, tags:['salad', 'wine']},
    {name:'sleep', duration:'420', enjoy: true, time:1455063275, tags:['bed', 'romance']}
]
```

I'm having a hard time understanding how to use this data in a neural network to predict if future actions would be enjoyable. Additionally, I want to find hidden relationships between various activities.

Not sure how to get the rubber on the road. How do I feed the network my array of objects and read the results?

If anyone can answer this within the context of https://github.com/cazala/synaptic that would be great. It's also super if the answer is a straight machine learning lesson.

Thanks all!

Comment: Sure thing, Skynet. Joking aside, neural networks are a *huge* topic and I believe this question is too broad for the Stack Overflow format. [See here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) to get an idea of what questions do fit here.

Comment: It is a broad topic with plenty of resources around the skynets. However, i can't find anywhere that shows how to feed a javascript object to a NN.

I hope a correct answer will show how to normailze the json data and show how to feed it through. The simpler the example, the better.

Comment: @MikeC could you recommend a better place to ask for this answer?

Comment: An object is just a collection of values. [You can see from their example here](http://synaptic.juancazala.com/#/) how they're feeding in the positions and velocities of the "creatures" to the network. You just have to setup a similar system of feeding inputs. How you feed them and update them is completely up to your implementation.

Comment: still looking for an answer? I could help if still necessary :)

Comment: This question is literally the topic of [this Synaptic documentation page](https://github.com/cazala/synaptic/wiki/Normalization-101). If you do not understand it, you are welcome to post a specific question (i.e. which part of it is unclear for you).

Answer (score 1):

I've written some JavaScript libraries to some basic machine learning, if you're still looking to try some stuff out with your data set. Though the libraries meet the requirements of ML in JavaScript, they aren't ANNs.

Naive Bayes Model: https://github.com/csbuja/NaiveBayesJS

K Nearest Neighbors Model: https://github.com/csbuja/KNNJS